# Xcode Display Name and Danish Characters causes Xcode to fail

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I'm developing an app with Swift + Spritekit with the project name as simple as "learningApp".

A good step and several hours into the development my team decided to name the app (with danish letters) "Lær Toner" (which in English means to learn tones).

However, when doing so - the entire project fails in Xcode. The .swift and .sks scene-files are not able to communicate and the console outputs this message:

```
2019-10-31 00:09:47.549357+0100 Lær Toner[18206:292858] Unable to load custom class 'LaunchScreen' from module '(null)'
```

Just to be clear, here's images:

[image]

[image]

So if I change the name to "Learn Tones" there are no issues at all and the app works as intended. As soon as I change it back to "Lær Toner" and run the app the console outputs the message above.

I tried to change it via "Build Settings" also - I also tried to reboot Xcode, clean the build folder, but nothing have helped so far.

I can see in the Danish App store that multiple applications have Danish letters like Æ, Ø and Å in the name, so that leads to think it's (hopefully) a minor thing I've missed.

I've searched the world wide web till the end, but I have not found anything close to a solution to this issue.

If anyone has any input, or knows how to deal with this, I'd be a happy developer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you just change the `Display Name`, there will be no problem you mentioned, it looks more like you changed the file directory.

Comment: @Nullable if I change 'Display Name' to a name which contains Danish letters Xcode fails with the mentioned error code. If change 'Display Name' back to english, then there is no issue.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the issue. I created a new demo `SpriteKit` project using Swift 5 and Xcode 11.2, changing the display name to **Lær Toner** but everything works perfectly.

Comment: which version of xCode you are using?

Comment: That's a feature not a bug, source: I'm swedish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the same issue when i have changed the display name from the 'General' tab of my target settings.

The solution is;

- Go back to the previous name by discarding the changes you have made, and make sure the app is running correctly.
- Uninstall the app from your device or simulator.
- Clean the project.
- The important thing is to add a new key on your info.plist

```
<key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
<string>Lær Toner</string>
```

And it will be ok.

Comment: Thank you so much, Mourad! It works perfectly - this has been bugging me for quite some time now. Thank you! :)